# ACTION_VIEW for opening url not working

Tags: android, image, url, actionview

/
/
I am using ACTION_VIEW to open a image URL. Below is the code

```
ImageView _presImage1= (ImageView) view_local.findViewById(R.id.img_prescription1);
    Picasso.with(this.getContext()).load(img_url).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(_presImage1);

    _presImage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Log.i("ABHINAY","Image is clicked:" + img_url);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(img_url),"image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

But the image is not opening on clicking. The url passed is valid and is opening properly in browser.

Below is the xml file i am using

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/primary">

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_prescription1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:src = "@drawable/bg_nav"/>

                <com.medquil.medquil.views.MyTextView android:padding = "4dp"
                    android:id="@+id/doctor_name"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                    android:textColor = "@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Dr. Abhishek Ekbote"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                <com.medquil.medquil.views.MyTextView android:padding = "4dp"
                    android:id="@+id/prescription_date"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="12th March 2016"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/primary">

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_prescription2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:src = "@drawable/bg_nav"/>

                <com.medquil.medquil.views.MyTextView android:padding = "4dp"
                    android:id="@+id/doctor_name1"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                    android:textColor = "@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Dr. Abhishek Ekbote"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                <com.medquil.medquil.views.MyTextView android:padding = "4dp"
                    android:id="@+id/prescription_date1"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="12th March 2016"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Below is the Java Function

```
private void addPrescriptionChilddouble(final String img_url, String name, String created_date, final String img_url1, String name1, String created_date1) {
    LayoutInflater li= (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.parentMedicalHistory);
    final View view_local=li.inflate(R.layout.fragment_medical_history_child_double, null);

    //FIRST
    TextView doctor_name=(TextView) view_local.findViewById(R.id.doctor_name);
    TextView date_created=(TextView) view_local.findViewById(R.id.prescription_date);

    int count=ll.getChildCount();count++;
    doctor_name.setText(name);
    date_created.setText(created_date);
    ImageView _presImage1= (ImageView) view_local.findViewById(R.id.img_prescription1);
    Picasso.with(this.getContext()).load(img_url).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(_presImage1);

    _presImage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Log.i("ABHINAY","Image is clicked:" + img_url);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(img_url),"image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //SECOND
    TextView doctor_name1=(TextView) view_local.findViewById(R.id.doctor_name1);
    TextView date_created1=(TextView) view_local.findViewById(R.id.prescription_date1);

    doctor_name1.setText(name1);
    date_created1.setText(created_date1);
    ImageView _presImage2= (ImageView) view_local.findViewById(R.id.img_prescription2);
    Picasso.with(this.getContext()).load(img_url1).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(_presImage2);

    _presImage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Log.i("ABHINAY", "Image is clicked:" + img_url1);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(img_url1),"image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ll.addView(view_local);
}
```

Comment: Is image loaded in `ImageView` from that URL ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Yes the image is loaded to ImageView

Comment: Hiding status bar is considered as loading showing image in full size like `imgView.setSystemUiVisibility( View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN );`. Have you tried that ?

Answer (score 0):

if the image is located in a  remote url like `http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg` use this code in your `OnClickListener()`:

```
String url = "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

but if you  are trying to display an image which is in your local resources like assets folder you can't display it in browse and you could dipslay the image through the use of a `WebView`!